# javascript function call fails

Tags: javascript

Why cant I work out with this function in my js:
error: ReferenceError: new_tweet is not defined

```
  function new_tweet(){
         alert("here i am");
  }

  function add_div(){
    mydiv = document.getElementById("new_twt");
    mydiv.innerHTML="<input type='button' value='You have new conversations' onclick=new_tweet();>";
  }
```

Comment: ReferenceError: new_tweet is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are doing this in some kind of load handler, which means that `new_tweet` is not global and therefore not available when you click the button. Try defining `new_tweet` in a global scope.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/DUbc3/

Answer (score 1):

try adding ' to onclick

```
<input type='button' value='You have new conversations' onclick='new_tweet()'>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Answer (score 1):

```
var newTweet = function (e) {
     alert("here i am");
}

function add_div(){
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = 'You have new conversations';
    button.onclick = newTweet;
    document.getElementById("new_twt").appendChild(button);
}

add_div();
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DUbc3/1/